# c# Assigning a reference

Tags: c#, initialization, assign

I have an issue with a `Lab` for `class` and the issue is I'm not sure how to assign my reference.

Here is my **Code :**

```
class Bank
{
    static List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    static Account active_account; // this will be an active 
    // Account (reference) retrieved from 
    // the bank. This will need to initialised either by 
    // CreateAccount or by RetrieveAccount.

    static void Main()
    {
        bool running = true, valid_option = false;
        int user_option = 0, account_num = 0, account_pin = 0;
        string name = "", type = "";
        decimal balance = 0, credit = 0;
        Bank chosen = new Bank();

        Console.Write("account number:");
                    account_num = SafeReadInteger(0);
                    Console.Write("pin number:");
                    account_pin = SafeReadInteger(0);
                    Console.Write("Client name:");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Balance:");
                    balance = SafeReadDecimal(0);
                    Console.Write("type:");
                    type = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("Credit:");
                    credit = SafeReadDecimal(0);
        chosen.CreateAccount(account_num, account_pin, name, balance, type);
    }
}
```

The comments are from the lecturer,

Now scrolling down to my constructor,

```
public Account CreateAccount(int ac_num_, int pin_, string owner_, decimal balance_, string type)
{
    Account newAcc = null;

    newAcc = new Account(ac_num_, pin_, owner_, balance_, type); // first uses the         constructor to create an account
    accounts.Add(newAcc); // second it inserts the account in the list and return the       reference to the account
    // depending on the type of account, a credit limit is set
    active_account = new Account(ac_num_, pin_);
    return newAcc;
}
```

My question is where do I Initialize `active_account` and to what do i assign it?

Comment: I find the style of marking the method parameters with trailing underscores compelling. Is it your invention or something dictated by the lecturer. Or do you have a styling engine of some sort that recommended it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CreateAccount method is not a constructor. It is a factory method. It works like this:

```
active_account = chosen.CreateAccount(
    account_num, account_pin, name, balance, type);

active_account.DoStuff();
```

Your Bank instance has a factory method named CreateAccount which returns an initialized instance of an Account class.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code provided, active_account is used to hold the current active account that has just been created, or when someone logs in.

It is being initialized in the CreateAccount() function you posted. Similarly, your RetrieveAccount() function would call the database and assign active_account to a new Account object as well.